# Completely hard edge in weight paint?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have a very low poly half peeled banana object, and the peels all have bones as they are to be animated. I'd like to have bones that ONLY affect the peels and don't deform the rest of the banana even slightly. The peels are just planes btw. The problem is I haven't found a way to do this in weight paint mode because no matter what if I paint a peel completely red, there will be a gradient touching and affecting the actual banana and neighboring peels a little bit. Shown here:
[image]

How can I completely remove that weight gradient so that it's hard transition from red to blue? Is it even possible? Is there a better way to rig this object?

Comment: You could either separate the peels from the rest of the mesh or you can assign weights to vertex groups.

Comment: As per the name, Vertex Groups are on a per-vertex basis, not per face. So even if you weight paint two adjacent vertices to be solid red and blue, in the viewport you will always see a gradient across the face connecting them. The vertices, however, will still deform sharply as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the banana part in *Edit* mode and in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, in the dropdown menu on the right, click on *Remove from All Groups*, so that this part of the mesh is not part of any group:

[image]